# Replacing Text In Notepad ++ using regular expression syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, string, notepad++

I have multiple lines in my text file like example

```
insert into (1,2,3,{ts '2016-01-19 14:41:33.0'},11,null,null);
insert into (1,2,3,{ts '2019-05-20 19:48:34.0'},11,null,null);
```

I want to replace all the lines in my file if it starts with `{ts` and replace it with `sysdate()`

I have tried using this following regular expression but it is not working `^\{ts.*`

Comment: Remove `^` caret sign from your regex,  it'll be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex `(\{ts ')([^']+)('\})`
This will check **{ts'** in the start of expression and takes everything up to ' and append **'}**

P.S. Don't forget to check Regular expression checkbox :)
[image]

Comment: You are welcome :) Also, you could accept my answer to make it done.

Answer (score 1):

`^` character means: beginning of the string. Since the group `\{ts` is placed in the between at the string, you should remove it: `\{ts.*`

If you want to use it with javascript, you can also use `g` flag to replace it multiple times: `/\{ts.*/g`

---

Since you've updated the question, you may want to update the pattern, too:

`\{ts[\s'\d-:\.]+}`

This pattern will match the substring inside the input: `{ts '2016-01-19 14:41:33.0'}`

`{` and `}` in this case means: starts with `{` and ends with `}`

`\s'\d-:\.` means: space character, number, and special characters

`[]+` means: character inside this group can be matched one or more times